# ¿Como calcular TFIDF con una lista que se le ha aplicado Lematización en Python?

Tags: python

Buen día.

Soy algo nueva en python y estoy buscando calcular el TFIDF para una lista de palabras a las cuales previamente le he aplicado lematización. El código que utilizo para hacer la lematización es el siguiente:

```
from textblob import TextBlob 
  
def pos_tagger(sentence): 
    sent = TextBlob(sentence) 
    tag_dict = {"J": 'a', "N": 'n', "V": 'v', "R": 'r'} 
    words_tags = [(w, tag_dict.get(pos[0], 'n')) for w, pos in sent.tags]     
    lemma_list = [wd.lemmatize(tag) for wd, tag in words_tags] 
    return lemma_list 

lemma_list = []

for i in range(len(result)):
    lemma_list.append(pos_tagger(result[i]))
    
lemma_list
```

De aquí obtento la lista "lemma_list" la cual está compuesta de 57 documentos. A pesar de que la lista está separada por palabras (ver foto #1), el tamaño de la lista es 57, es decir, lo toma con base a la cantidad de documentos que la conforman y no por el total de palabras (aclaro esto pues creo que es relevante).

[image: foto #1]

Posterior a esto, aplico una eliminación de Stop Words y la función 'lower' para colocar en minúsculas mis palabras. El código que utilizo y que aparentemente funciona es:

```
filtered_sent=[]

for doc in lemma_list:
    for palabra in doc:
        pal = palabra.lower()
        if pal not in stop_words:
            filtered_sent.append(pal)
        
print("\n Palabras filtradas:",filtered_sent)
```

Sin embargo la lista "filtered _sent" no la utilizo para el cálcuo del TF-IDF (la utilizo para otras funciones) pues lo que busco en este paso es crear un Data Frame en el cual por filas estén los 57 documentos y en las columnas las palabras con la lematización aplicada.

Por lo tanto es con la lista "lemma_list" que busco hacer el cálculo del TF-IDF por medio del siguiente código:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

def tfidf(text, vectorizer):
    doc_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(text)
    return pd.DataFrame(doc_matrix.toarray(), columns = vectorizer.get_feature_names())

vector =  TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = stop_words, norm="l1", lowercase = True)

data_fin = tfidf(lemma_list, vector)
data_fin
```

Pero estoy obteniendo el siguiente error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-37a3a8217c2d> in <module>
      2 warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
      3 
----> 4 data_fin = tfidf(lemma_list, vector)
      5 data_fin

<ipython-input-49-9e0530acbdae> in tfidf(text, vectorizer)
      2 
      3 def tfidf(text, vectorizer):
----> 4     doc_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(text)
      5     return pd.DataFrame(doc_matrix.toarray(), columns = vectorizer.get_feature_names())
      6 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   1848         """
   1849         self._check_params()
-> 1850         X = super().fit_transform(raw_documents)
   1851         self._tfidf.fit(X)
   1852         # X is already a transformed view of raw_documents so

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   1201         max_features = self.max_features
   1202 
-> 1203         vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents,
   1204                                           self.fixed_vocabulary_)
   1205 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in _count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
   1113         for doc in raw_documents:
   1114             feature_counter = {}
-> 1115             for feature in analyze(doc):
   1116                 try:
   1117                     feature_idx = vocabulary[feature]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in _analyze(doc, analyzer, tokenizer, ngrams, preprocessor, decoder, stop_words)
    102     else:
    103         if preprocessor is not None:
--> 104             doc = preprocessor(doc)
    105         if tokenizer is not None:
    106             doc = tokenizer(doc)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in _preprocess(doc, accent_function, lower)
     67     """
     68     if lower:
---> 69         doc = doc.lower()
     70     if accent_function is not None:
     71         doc = accent_function(doc)

**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'**
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda que me ayude a resolver este error. Gracias!

Comment: le estas pasando una lista a algo que debe de operar con strings. No conozco a profundidad ninguna de las librerías que usas y para saber como corregir el error se necesita poder reproducir el error, lo cual no se puede por que faltan los datos de entrada y salida esperada. Por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/510721/edit) tu pregunta

Comment: Hola Christian, gracias por tu respuesta.Tienes razón, omití información importante, ya la agregué.En cuanto a la función lower tengo entendido que funciona con cadenas pero en realidad ese no es problema porque es función la aplico con éxito en un paso previo al cálculo del TFIDF, lo que creo que ocurre es que como la función TFIDF tiene dentro de sus argumentos "lowercase" y dentro de esta no tengo forma de convertir la lista en cadena es que me surje el error.He intentado definir a lemma_list como string, colocar de tal forma: tfidf(str(lemma_list),vector) pero con esto me surje otro error.

Comment: `lemma_list` pareciera una lista de listas, pero  según la documentación `fit_transform` estaría esperando en todo caso una lista de cadenas.

Comment: creo que la observación de patricio es correcta. Intenta haciendo `doc_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(text[0])`

Comment: Hola Patricio, tEfectivamente cuando ejecuto lo que Christian propone desaparece el error sin embargo en la filas me quedan las palabras y no el documento, en este caso el de la posición 0. Saben cómo puedo arreglarlo? Nuevamente muchas gracias por sus comentarios